# Do we have $K \cap P = (K \cap M)(K \cap N)$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over a $p$-adic field $k$, let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup with Levi $M$ and radical $N$.  Let $K$ be a maximal open compact subgroup of $G$ in good position relative to $P$, so that $G = PK$.  Under what circumstances do we have $P \cap K = (M \cap K)(N \cap K)$?

My motivation is the following: it is a common convention, e.g. in Harish-Chandra's notes, to normalize a left or right Haar measure on each closed subgroup $H$ of $G$ so that $H \cap K$ has measure one.  Supposing we do this for $M$ and $N$, then we get a left Haar measure $d_lp$ on $P$ satisfying:

$$\int\limits_P f(p)d_lp = \int\limits_M \int\limits_N f(mn) dndm$$
My question is then equivalent to the assertion that the Haar measure on $P$ in this way follows the convention that $P \cap K$ has measure one (taking $f = \operatorname{Char} P \cap K$).

I'm not even sure about the unramified case.  Here $G$ comes from a smooth affine group scheme $\mathcal G$ over $\mathcal O_K$, and $K = \mathcal G(\mathcal O_K) = G(\mathcal O_K)$.  So should $P, M, N$ as $\mathcal P, \mathcal M, \mathcal N$.  We would have $P \cap K = (M \cap K)(N \cap K)$ if the product map $M \times_k N \rightarrow P$ comes from an isomorphism of $\mathcal O_K$-schemes $\mathcal M \times_{\mathcal O_K} \mathcal N \rightarrow \mathcal P$.

Comment: This is a weakened form (i.e., it holds for more subgroups) of the notion of $K$ having an Iwahori decomposition with respect to $P$, which demands that $K = (\overline N \cap K)(M \cap K)(N \cap K)$ (from which your desired equality follows since $P \cap \overline N = \{1\}$).  In particular, it holds for all Moy–Prasad filtration subgroups with respect to points $x$ in the building of $M$.

Comment: @LSpice This is true but unfortunately insufficient since D_S wants K maximal.

Comment: @PaulBroussous, thanks; I missed that.

Comment: @LSpice In their article "Structure Theory Via Types", Bushnell and Kutzko claim that this is true if $K$ is special and refer to Tits, Corvalis. I do not have Tits's article with me.

Comment: @PaulBroussous, I'm sure it follows from the material there (what doesn't?), but I don't find an exact statement.

Comment: (By the way, my [initial comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317358/do-we-have-k-cap-p-k-cap-mk-cap-n#comment792680_317358) should have specified that it referred to *positive-depth* MP subgroups, which is why, as @PaulBroussous points out, it's insufficient.)

Comment: Maybe this article by G. Henniart and M.-F. Vigneras is helpful: [A Satake isomorphism for representations modulo $p$ of reductive groups over local fields](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/%7Evigneras/satake_isomorphism-07032012.pdf), especially 6.5 Theorem.